# azurerm_virtual_machine_extension - on azurerm_windows_virtual_machine with count not working

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` section that looks like this

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "InstallCts" {
  name                 = "Install_Cts"
  virtual_machine_id   = "${element(azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.myserver.*.id, count.index )}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

settings = <<SETTINGS
    {   
    "fileUris": [ "https://someurl_server.ps1}" ],
    "commandToExecute": "powershell someurl_server.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS


}
```

I keep getting the below error msge

```
The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data"
blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

Does `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` work well with `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` with `count` or it is not compatible? Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error display, you should define the `count` in the resource `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` section. Note that the extension `Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.CustomScript` is used for [Linux VMs extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux), you can change it like below to work with Windows VMs.

```
 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "InstallCts" {
  count                = length(var.vm_names)              # specify here
  name                 = "Install_Cts"
  virtual_machine_id   = "${element(azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.rg.*.id, count.index )}"
 # publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
 # type                 = "CustomScript"
 # type_handler_version = "2.0"

   publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
   type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
   type_handler_version = "1.8"

settings = <<SETTINGS
    {   
    "fileUris": [ "https://someurl_server.ps1}" ],
    "commandToExecute": "powershell someurl_server.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS

}
```

For example, the below command works for me to add a web server in each VM.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar kidda issue on github. It's closed but I think it covers your issue too. Have a look at this:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5675